# Unicode & Circled numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

Looking at circled numbers, Unicode and experimenting I found out that I could print this character **㉛** in swift using this code:

```
print("N:\u{325B}:") // Prints N:㉛:
```

I would like to print it the following way (or similar), that is put the value 0x325B in a variable before feeding it to `print`, but that does not work:

```
let v = 0x325B
print(“N:\u{\(v)}:”) // Prints N:㉛:
```

Does anyone know how to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UnicodeScalar` to convert your `Int` value to your `Character`:

```
let v = 0x325B
print("N:\(UnicodeScalar(v)):") // prints N:㉛:
```